# Copy data from an lParam value to a RECT structure in VB6

Tags: pointers, vb6, subclassing, copymemory

I am trying to get the rect from `lParam` while subclassing `WM_MOVING`.

My code currently is

```
Public Declare Function CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (pDest As Any, pSource As Any, ByVal dwLength As Long) As Long

Public Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Dim r As RECT
CopyMemory r, lParam, Len(r)
```

But the values of `r` are so absurd (like left: 1633872, right: 219218039, bottom: 1) that I think I am doing something wrong.

Does anybody see my error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am now using the fool-safe

```
Private Declare Function CopyFromLParamToRect Lib "user32" Alias "CopyRect" (lpDestRect As RECT, ByVal lpSourceRect As Long) As Long
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration and code is passing a pointer to `lParam` which itself is a pointer to the structure.

You should adjust the calling code to pass the `lParam` value "by value" so `CopyMemory` gets the actual data pointer:

```
CopyMemory r, ByVal lParam, Len(r)
```

Using the generic declaration for `CopyMemory` that you had originally means you can pass a pointer to anything, or a pointer value itself with the `ByVal` keyword.

```
'Copy data out
CopyMemory r, ByVal lParam, Len(r)

'Modify r

'Copy data back in
CopyMemory ByVal lParam, r, Len(r)
```

Alternativly, you can create strongly typed alias as per your other answer.